# Javascript - How to check the value of an array using a variable as the key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a simple array like this:

```
const arr = {
    name: 'Lorem',
    age: 'Ipsum',
}
```

How would I check the value of `name` based on a variable that is, for example, set on click of a button? Here's what I tried:

```js
const arr = {
    name: 'Lorem',
    age: 'Ipsum',
}

$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
  // this:
  console.log(arr.key);
  // should return the same result as this:
  console.log(arr.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-key="name">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `arr[key]` Also, that is an object, not an array.

Comment: @iz_ thank you for both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the bracket notation:

```js
const arr = { name: 'Lorem', age: 'Ipsum' };

$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const key = $(this).attr('data-key');
  console.log(arr[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-key="name">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Arr.key takes the keyword "key" Literally, and does not replace your variable in with the key name. You need to add brackets like so to perform this action:

```
arr[key];
```

Doing it this way will replace the literal term "key" with the variable you have assigned to it.